# Search link with regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I am new in regular expression.

I have this text:

```
$text =
'<ul style="list-style:none;">
  <li>
      <a href="files/docs/qwe.xls" target="_blank">Link1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
      <a href="files/docs/ere.xls" target="_blank">Link2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
      <a href="files/docs/123.xls" target="_blank">Link3</a>
  </li>
</ul>';
```

with regular expression I want to get this arrays:

```
$filePath[0] = "files/docs/qwe.xls";
$fileName[0] = "Link1";
$filePath[1] = "files/docs/ere.xls";
$fileName[1] = "Link2";
$filePath[2] = "files/docs/123.xls";
$fileName[2] = "Link3";
```

How can I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Ideally one should not be parsing HTML with regular expressions, even the slightest changes in the text will tend to mess up your regexps.
Please take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
$res = array();
preg_match_all('/href="(.+?)".*?>(.+?)<\/a>/ims', $text, $res);
var_dump($res);
```

Comment: @Robert: Why to define $res first?

Comment: Because it will give error of undefined array moreover it's good habbit to declare variables that you're going to use. Btw your code will fail with multiline

Comment: But $res gets defined by preg_match_all and it does not throws a php error at all, even if I enable E_ALL error_reporting(). Multiline was not a requirement.

Comment: `$res` is not defined by preg_match_all! Check the manual. As param preg_match_all takes reference to object. Reference means that object needs to exists before it's passed to function. http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Comment: Okay, but then we have to fix the doc and its examples overthere at php.net don't we?

Comment: I don't understand u declaration param for matches is `array &$matches` which means the reference to array. Reference rather refers to objects that exists.

Answer (score 2):

You need simple regular expression

check this code

```
 $match = array();
 preg_match_all('#<a href="(.*?)">(.*?)</a>#sm', $text, $match);
 print_r($match)
```

`(.*?)` - means everything non greedy

Comment: Fails if tags are written in uppercase <A HREF="">... add #ims instead of #sm for this at end of the expression.

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER did the op write that uppercase is needed? It's just about adding "i" to "#sm" :)

Comment: Yeah I know but you wrote in my answer that my code is not working with multiline and this was nod needed either bei the op an his example. So I thought I'll complete your answer too.

Comment: his example isn't written in 1 line, is it?

Comment: It is not but my regex didn't need to match multi lines in the example above. It would only need to match multi lines if the <a href="...">...</a> part is on multiple lines. But it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Use lookarounds, they are useful to check if there is something before or after the string you're looking for. Here is how it works:

```
/(?<=href=")[^"]*(?=")/
```

Here is what it means:

`/` beginning
`(?<=href=")` preceded by `href="`
`[^"]*` any nomber of non-`"` characters
`(?=")` followed by `"`
`/` end